# Take test or obtain result 72 hours before arrival? (Flying to Lithuania)

Tags: air-travel, europe, covid-19

I am going to take a flight from Norway to Lithuania in about 4 days from now. I am planning to take the PGR Covid test, as it is one of the accepted tests for entering Lithuania. There is a requirement to do this within 72 hours of arrival. I wonder if I must **take the test** within the time interval or **obtain the result of the test** within the time interval (in the latter case possibly taking the test earlier than 72 hours before arrival)?

Here is what Ryanair specifies in [a travel update of June 17](https://www.ryanair.com/content/dam/ryanair/comms-2020/NEW_Other_Markets_Travel-_Update_17JUN.pdf):

> All pax returning or arriving to Lithuania must have a document (in one of the official languages of the European Union) stating a negative C-19 disease (coronavirus infection) test result obtained no earlier than 72 hrs before returning or arrival. A serological antibody test result shall not be accepted. Test locations at Kaunas and Palanga. For further information and exemptions click here. Confirmation of completed electronic form (QR code) is also requested. For further entry information click here for English or here for Lithuanian.

Answer (score 5):

I dug deeper and found that it most likely is the **time of taking the test**, not obtaining the result. E.g.

> asmenims nuo 7 iki 16 metų, turintiems ne anksčiau nei 72 valandų laikotarpiu (**skaičiuojant nuo ėminio paėmimo momento**) atlikto SARS-CoV-2 PGR tyrimo arba ne anksčiau nei 48 valandų laikotarpiu (**skaičiuojant nuo ėminio paėmimo momento**) atlikto antigeno testo COVID-19 ligai (koronaviruso infekcijai) nustatyti neigiamą rezultatą (išskyrus asmenis, kurie 14 dienų laikotarpiu iki grįžimo / atvykimo į Lietuvos Respubliką lankėsi šalyse, Paveiktų šalių sąraše priskirtose šalims, iš kurių atvykus taikomos sustiprintos užkrečiamųjų ligų kontrolės priemonės)

as can be found in the [Registry of Legal Acts](https://www.e-tar.lt/portal/en/legalAct/6863cf50651d11eabee4a336e7e6fdab/OxGKHseenM). The text in bold reads "counting from taking the sample". The quoted text does not directly apply to my case but considers a particular exception from the general rule. However, I think this indicates quite generally how they count the time w.r.t. Covid-19 tests.